# how to keep an image on top of other image

Tags: android

can anyone let me know how to keep an image on top of other image. If we select a portion of the top image it should display the below image portion.

Please share the samp

Thanks in advance.
-pavan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would completely answer your question... but firstly, images shouldn't really ever overlap in a LinearLayout. If you're using a RelativeLayout, they definitely can overlap, and the image on top will be whatever was loaded last in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're attempting to do - kind of transparency (so to speak) of the top image so that portions of the bottom image are displayed along with portions of the top image ... I do things like that all the time by overriding the onDraw() method on my View to handle the image painting myself.  There's allot of examples on the net for this - simple stuff.